# How to calculate a p value for Williams trend test in r (Similar function of "PROBMC" in SAS)

Tags: r, sas

I want to calculate p values for William trend test in R, given that I have already known the t statistics. 
In SAS, I can use function PROBMC as shown below

```
 PROBMC(distribution, q, prob, df, nparms<, parameters>)
```

Below is an example

```
       if parameters t=2.6,  k = 6, [nu] = 42, and t = 2.60 then probability is .9924467341.
       using (prob=probmc("williams",2.6,.,42,6);)
```

Is there a similar function in R to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably out of luck.

Using `library("sos"); findFn("Williams trend distribution")` and searching through the results finds two packages, `PMCMCR` and `StatCharrms`, that have functions to perform the Williams test, but it looks like these only use the tabulated values from the paper to get critical values for p=0.05 - not compute the distribution/p-value directly.

The computation to get the full distribution/p-values looks pretty hairy, making it less likely that someone will have decided to implement it in R. As described in the [SAS documentation for the PROBMC function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p06idazwtugz0an1rlks4swmutms.htm)

> As described in Williams (1971) (See References ), the full computation is extremely lengthy and is carried out in three stages.

This would make a nice computational statistics project for someone ...

[image]